# Binding HTML table with templates with CSS grid

Tags: html, css, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an HTML table that is being generated through templates that looks like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Value1</th>
    <th>Value2</th>
    <th>Value3</th>
    <th>Value4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#each []}}
<tr>
    <td>{{this.val1}}</td>
    <td>{{this.val2}}</td>
    <td>{{this.val3}}</td>
    <td>{{this.val4}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

And I want to edit its design through a css file which consists of cell data, like this:

```
.newCell70 div {
width: 66px;
text-align: right;
}

.cell80 div {
width: 76px;
}

.newCell80 div {
width: 76px;
text-align: right;
}

.cell90 div {
width: 86px;
}
```

I have a large number of cells of this kind.  How do I allow the contents of my table to generate with the specific design parameters for each cell?

Answer (score 0):

This is what your gonna wanna use, I cannot give you an example because your question should be a little more specific but check this out

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

```
:nth-child(number) {
css declarations;
}
```